# how to set the integer value to tag of button coming from database in table row

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tableview

I want to set the value to button tag either one or zero, these values are coming from database in table row.
when value is 1 I want that button image to be star.png and if value is 0 I want that buttons image to be dot.png.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats your question spikydude.

What it seems to me is you want to add a button on cell of tableView which image will be either star or dot. And that you can easily get from your dataBase. Simply add one `if`condition in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and you should get what you want/

EDIT:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    if(value==0)
    {
        //create your button with proper frame
        yourButton.tag = value;
        [yourButton setImage:[UIImage iamgeNamed:@"dot.png"];
    }
    else if(value==1)
    {
        //create your button with proper frame
       yourButton.tag = value;
       [yourButton setImage:[UIImage iamgeNamed:@"star.png"];
    }
    else
    {
    }
    return cell; 
}
```

Or if you want how to retrieve value from database, specify that.

Comment: hey but how should i relate it with button tag

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way how to do this if you have more than two pictures:

```
NSArray * picturesName = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"picture0.png",@"picture1.png", ... , nil];
UIImage * img;
if (value < [picturesName count]) {
    img = [UIImage imageNamed:[picturesName objectAtIndex:value]];
} else {
    img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"]
}
```

Then you can `setImage` of your button